# Making a Portable Executable using FASM in Ubuntu

Tags: assembly, x86, wine, fasm

Stack Community !

I am currently on Ubuntu 17.10 and an assembly language learner. When I was on Windows, I used a library named **'win32a.inc'** and **"MyLib.inc"** to **read_eax** and **print_hex**. The Syntax used to be like this:

```
format PE console
include 'win32a.inc'
entry start
section '.text' code readable executable
start:
     mov eax,0xffff
     call print_eax
push 0
call [ExitProcess]

include 'MyLib.inc'
```

But not having a good experience on Windows, made me switch to Linux. I did this to install fasm:

```
sudo apt-get install fasm
```

But when I try to make an executable (I plan to run it with wine) I get an error on terminal: **'win32a.inc' source file Missing.**

'win32a.inc' is a default fasm library on Windows. I don't know how I could use it in Linux. I have the backup of all the Windows Libraries though ;_;

> Is there a way I can make a portable executable in Linux using FASM ??

Comment: Did `win32a.inc` come with the Windows distribution of FASM?  Did you try getting a copy of it that way?  Does FASM make a PE executable if you don't try to include files you don't have?  If so, your question is "how do I get these FASM libraries", not "How do I make a PE".

Comment: win32a.inc came with the ›FASM for Windows‹-package (http://flatassembler.net/download.php), you cannot use it with linux, because the API and syscalls are very different. Assembly is not the language of choice for portable software. Nevertheless you could create custom libraries for windows and linux with the same functionality.

Comment: @fuz : his question says he will run his executable under wine.

Comment: @sivizius So, do I have to use Virtual Box under Linux running Win10 in order to make WINDOWS PORTABLE EXECUTABLE files??

Comment: no, you still can make windows-executables with fasm on linux, if you download the include-files for windows, but you cannot create linux-executables with the same file, as long you do not have libraries for windows and linux with the same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile to any type of files supported by FASM on any OS.

The trick is that Windows port of FASM treat the filenames as case insensitive, but Linux FASM treat them as case sensitive.

So, check the case of the file names used in the `include` directives.

The real filenames of the FASM default include libraries are **all UPPERCASE**. So, you need to use `WIN32A.INC` if you want to compile this code with the Linux (or any other Unix type OS) FASM.